# Generic builder of (almost) identical 3rd party classes

Tags: scala, generics, builder

I have a bunch of 3rd party classes, these classes are autogenerated in java and do not have any hierarchy

Here is the `RulesPropertyList`

```java
enum RulesPropertyType {...}
class RulesPropertyValue {...}

class RulesProperty {
    public RulesPropertyType getPropertyTypeCode(){...}
    public RulesPropertyValue getPropertyValue() {...}
}

class RulesPropertyList {
    public void setNumProperties(int numProperties)
    public void setProperties(RulesProperty[] properties)
}
```

And its `Characs*` sibling

```java
enum CharacsPropertyType {...}
class CharacsPropertyValue {...}

class CharacsProperty {
    public CharacsPropertyType getPropertyTypeCode(){...}
    public CharacsPropertyValue getPropertyValue() {...}
}

class CharacsPropertyList {
    public void setNumProperties(int numProperties)
    public void setProperties(CharacsProperty[] properties)
}
```

There are more than just `Rules*` and `Characs*` families of classes, and classes actually have more fields and deeper structures.
All classes are completely identical except for the prefixes in the class names.

Currently, I have a separate builder method for each set of classes.

```scala
def buildRulesPropertyList(props: (RulesPropertyType, RulesPropertValue): RulesPropertyList = {
  val properties = props.map { case (type, value) => 
    RulesProperty(type, value)
  }

  val propList = RulesPropertyList
  propList.setProperties(properties.toArray)
  propList.setNumProperties(properties.length)
  propList
}
```

I have to create such a builder for each family of classes.
Now I only see a possibility to make a generic builder using reflection.

Is there a way in Scala to make such a builder using generics in Scala language?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in Scala to make such a builder using generics in Scala language?

yes, but I don't think it's going to be any less code. I think your best move here is to just write some simple code generation for each type. you would feed it a list of family names like `Seq("Rules", "Characs", ...)` and have it spit out your `build${family}PropertyList` methods.

Comment: This is an option, will try it. Thanks!